# .htaccess redirect became a loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect the site so that when they type in jdeshotelandresort.com/admin, they shall be redirected to a file in JDESHotelandResort/ReservationProcess/Admin/admin-login.php

but the result becomes like this (it looped I suppose):

```
http://jdeshotelandresort.com/JDESHotelAndResort/ReservationProcess/Admin/admin-login.phpJDESHotelAndResort/ReservationProcess/Admin/admin-login.phpJDESHotelAndResort/ReservationProcess/Admin/admin-login.phpJDESHotelAndResort/ReservationProcess/Admin/admin-login.phpJDESHotelAndResort/ReservationProcess/Admin/admin-login.phpJDESHotelAndResort/ReservationProcess/Admin/admin-login.phpJDESHotelAndResort/ReservationProcess/Admin/admin-login.phpJDESHotelAndResort/ReservationProcess/Admin/admin-login.phpJDESHotelAndResort/ReservationProcess/Admin/admin-login.phpadmin
```

Here is the code inside my .htaccess:

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 /admin(.*) /JDESHotelAndResort/ReservationProcess/Admin/admin-login.php/$1
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much! =)

Comment: `^/admin` would only match admin if it's at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Change your rule to this:

```
Redirect 301 /admin /JDESHotelAndResort/ReservationProcess/Admin/admin-login.php
```

Comment: Clear your browser cache. Did you change it to redirect instead of redirectmatch as I specified?